# Confusion on whether this operational chain/product rule is correct?

Tags: partial-derivative, products, chain-rule

I'm focused on the expression

$$ \left(f(x,y) \frac{d}{dx} \right)^n$$ as an operator, and I'd like to calculate its partial derivatives when applied to a sufficiently differentiable function.

Can I assert that

$$ \frac{d}{dy} \left(f(x,y) \frac{d}{dx} \right)^n[g(x)] = \left( n\left(f(x,y) \frac{d}{dx} \right)^{n-1} \cdot f_y \frac{d}{dx} \right)[g(x)]?$$

Or is this generally the incorrect formula? If that's incorrect, the alternative I suspect is

$$\left( n\left(f(x,y) \frac{d}{dx} \right)^{n-1} \cdot \left(f_y \frac{d}{dx} + f \frac{d}{da} \frac{d}{dx} \right) \right)[g(x)]?$$

However, another poster brought up a fair point, which is to look at the case of $n = 1$ first. Because $\frac{d}{dx}$ is not a "function" though, I'm unsure whether my interpretation is correct for $n=1$ too.

What is $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( f(x,y) \frac{d}{dx} \right) \ \text{and} \ \frac{d}{dy} \left(f(x,y) \frac{d}{dx} \right)?$$

Comment: If you want to check your calculations it might be worth looking at the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$

Comment: But I don't necessarily know how to apply it to those cases either, I don't know if I need an extra product rule or not because $\frac{d}{dx}$ is not a function, it has somewhat different rules.

Comment: You do bring up a good point though, do you know the correct formulas for $n=1$?

Comment: Presumably you can consider  $f(x,y) \frac{d}{dx} g(x)$ and $f(x,y) \frac{d}{dx} \left( f(x,y) \frac{d}{dx} g(x) \right)$ - assuming that is the correct interpretation of what you are trying to do

Comment: @Henry Graham seems to suggest otherwise. I did too, which is why I asked, rightfully so it seems.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's *not* so easy as applying the **power rule**.

$\left[f(x,y)\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\right]^n$ is not the $n$-th exponential of a product of functions, *but rather* it is the $n$-th composition of product of a function and *a linear operator*.

Thus the **product rule** for derivation shall be involved *so* many times.

---

Examine a simple case:

$$\small\begin{align}\left[f(x,y)\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\right]^2&= \left[f(x,y) \tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\right]\!\left[f(x,y)\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\right] \\ &=\left[f(x,y)\tfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\tfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial x}+f(x,y)^2\tfrac{\partial^2~~~}{\partial x~^2}\right]\\[2ex]\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial y}\left[f(x,y)\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\right]^2&=\left[\tfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\tfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}+f(x,y)\tfrac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y~\partial x}\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}+f(x,y)\tfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\tfrac{\partial^2~~}{\partial y~\partial x}+2f(x,y)\tfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\tfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial x}+f(x,y)^2\tfrac{\partial^2~~}{\partial y~\partial x}\right]\\[2ex]\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial y}\left[f(x,y)\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial x}\right]^2 g(x)&=\tfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\tfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\tfrac{\mathrm d  g(x)}{\mathrm d x}+f(x,y)\tfrac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y~\partial x}\tfrac{\mathrm d g(x)}{\mathrm d  x}+2f(x,y)\tfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\tfrac{\mathrm d g(x)}{\mathrm d x}\end{align}$$

Comment: Interesting, does their exist a closed-form expression? How do we know the final fomula doesn't sim/plify to a $n-1$th power term, seeing as how this product can expand to so many terms?